# Benefits of Grouping in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I recently started a Udemy course on programming in c, and when the instructor was detailing how to set up a c project in VS Code, he had as go through the tasks.json file and add the following code. From a little bit of research, it seems that this is not necessary, but I am not entirely certain. If anyone could elaborate on the importance of the group>kind>build and isDefault>true lines in general, that would be fantastic.

```
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
```

As I said, I tried doing some online research, but nothing was clear, and was phrased in a "duh, you should know this", kind of tone, which really through off my understanding.

As a side note, this is my second ever question asked on stack overflow, and I would love some feedback on the formatting.

Comment: In some occasions VSCode looks for build tasks, especially the default one. For example, the key combination Ctrl+Shift+B runs the default build task.

Comment: have you read the `Tasks` doc page of VSC

Comment: The only place I found the purpose of `"isDefault"` explained was [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/QXbtfNQhcYQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't particularly well documented on the [VSCode Tasks page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) or [tasks schema page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix), so I was confused too. Here's my current understanding (which may have some holes in!)

The group's kind can be either `"test"` or `"build"`. Which you choose determine where the task is listed or run.

- A `"test"` task is listed/run when you choose the `Tasks: Run Test Task` command from the command palette.
- A `"build"` task is listed/run when you choose the `Tasks: Run Build Task` command from the command palette. By default, this also has a keyboard shortcut of cmd+shift+b (Mac) or ctrl-shift-b (Windows/Linux).

(The command palette can be shown with cmd+shift+p on Mac or ctrl+shift+p on Windows/Linux.)

If you only have one task of a certain kind, or have multiple but only one has `isDefault` set, then that task is run when the command above is invoked, otherwise the relevant tasks are listed and you can choose one. In my testing, `isDefault` is ignored if it's set for multiple tasks of the same kind.

The kind can either be provided as the only value or with the specific "`kind`" key:

```
"group": "test"
```

or

```
"group": {
    "kind": "test"
}
```

The reason to use the second form is that it allows you to specify the `isDefault` key as well (see above for what that does):

```
"group": {
    "kind": "test",
    "isDefault": true
}
```

Comment: In addition to "build" and "test", it seems like another task group kind that would be nice to support is "debug" – as a way to backreference the preLaunchTask and postDebugTask tasks in launch.json that are sometimes required on certain platforms when executing Step Debugging. Not sure where else to post this comment.

Comment: @JamesWilson nice idea. Maybe post a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=feature_request.md ?

Comment: Requested here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/205057 Thanks for the suggestion.